# XSLT that creates conditions and check the attribute inside the tag

Tags: xslt

How can I implement an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet that appends the character "w" to both tags  when the attribute "type" inside the tag  is equal to "WILD"?

```
<root>
    <Header>
        <farm>
            <Identity>0123</Identity>
        </farm>
        <Site>
            <Identity>0123</Identity>
        </Site>
    </Header>
    <body>
        <animal>
            <name place="ocean" type="WILD">
                <species>Tortoise</species>
            </name>
        </animal>
    </body>
</root>
```

**Result desired:**

```
<root>
    <Header>
        <farm>
            <Identity>0123w</Identity>
        </farm>
        <Site>
            <Identity>0123w</Identity>
        </Site>
    </Header>
    <body>
        <animal>
            <name place="ocean" type="WILD">
                <species>Tortoise</species>
            </name>
        </animal>
    </body>
</root>
```

I have tried to use this XSLT; however, if I change the attribute type to "XXX", then the result is incorrect; it still concating the "w"

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  
  <!-- identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- add 'w' to Identity elements inside <farm> and <Site> -->
  <xsl:template match="farm/Identity | Site/Identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="if (../name/@type='WILD') then . else concat(., 'w')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- add 'w' to Identity elements inside <name> with attribute 'type' = 'WILD' -->
  <xsl:template match="name[@type='WILD']/Identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(., 'w')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your example is ambiguous: will there always be only one Header and one body with one animal? If not, what links an animal to Identity?

Comment: hi @michael.hor257k, there is always one header and one animal. I've just updated the questions.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="type" select="/root/body/animal/name/@type" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Identity[$type='WILD']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>  
        <xsl:text>w</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

To do it the way you started, it would need to be something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Identity">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>  
        <xsl:if test="../../../body/animal/name/@type='WILD'">w</xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to write a stylesheet with an identity transform to copy everything, and add a specific template to add the `w` character as needed.

Assuming your example XML is representative, and there's only one `animal` in each XML document:

```xml
<xsl:template match="/root[body/animal/name/@type='WILD']/header/*/Identity/text()">
   <xsl:copy/>
   <xsl:text>w</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Conal, it will have always only one animal

Comment: OK so my template should do what you need. It matches the text node inside an `Identity` element if the animal is wild, copies the text node, and then adds a single character `w`.